# Return selection of fields from a Model in django

Tags: django, model, field

Hay guys, i want to use something like this

```
users = User.objects.all()
```

but i only want to return a couple of fields for each result, say 'name' and 'email'. This data is going t be turned into JSON data, and some fields in my model are sensitive.

How would i do this in django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `values` or `values_list`:

```
>>> User.objects.values('name', 'email')
[{'name': 'Daniel', 'email':'daniel@whatever.com'}, ...]

>>> User.objects.values_list('name', 'email')
[['Daniel', 'daniel@whatever.com'], ...]
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-fields).